# Getting values from Excel using OpenNTF POI, but row.getCellType() no longer working

Tags: java, apache-poi, xpages

I am using latest POI version from OpenNTF on a Domino 10 server using the UpdateSite

https://poi4xpages.openntf.org/

My code reads cell values in Excel

for some reason the method rowdata.getCell(0).getCellType() no longer works and generate errors when running so I can't check what type of value the cell contain.

The methods **getStringCellValue()** and **getNumericCellValue()** only works if the value in the Excel cells is of that type, i.e if I have a cell containing **100** it is always a number.

in my columns I have both **100** and **100a** and if I use **100a** with **getNumericCellValue()** it generates an error.

```
hsCurrent.put("FILE", inputFile);
Workbook wb = ioAction.run(null, hsCurrent);
worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
rowdata = worksheet.getRow(1);
kod = rowdata.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
price = rowdata.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
```

as the **getCellType()** is not working I need to find another way to deal with the errors I get, How can I do that in java.

also, if you have any idea why there is a problem with **getCellType()**, let me know.

also note that all these methods check the **value** of the cell in excel, **not** what typ of cell it is

let me know if I need to provide more information

[image]

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.getCellType()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType; (loaded from file:/D:/Lotus/Domino/Data/domino/workspace/.config/org.eclipse.osgi/42/0/.cp/lib-maven/poi.jar by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@ab93247a[biz.webgate.dominoext.poi.library:1.3.1.201703140726(id=42)]) called from class com.consili.ImportExcel (loaded from xspnsf://server:0/web.nsf/WEB-INF/classes/ by com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader@9b55621b). at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.handleError(FacesServlet.java:690) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.renderErrorPage(FacesServlet.java:512) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:186) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103) </values>
    <values>at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:600) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1352) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:877) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:820) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:589) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1336) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357) at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter</values>
    <values>.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313) at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.getCellType()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType; (loaded from file:/D:/Lotus/Domino/Data/domino/workspace/.config/org.eclipse.osgi/42/0/.cp/lib-maven/poi.jar by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@ab93247a[biz.webgate.dominoext.poi.library:1.3.1.201703140726(id=42)]) called from class com.consili.ImportExcel (loaded from xspnsf://server:sweb.nsf/WEB-INF/classes/ by com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader@9b55621b). at com.consili.ImportExcel.getImportedData(ImportExcel.java:98) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.i</values>
    <values>nvoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:322) at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTVariableDecl.interpret(ASTVariableDecl.java:82) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:90) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435) at com.</values>
    <values>ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:732) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234) at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222) at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111) at com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60) at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcas</values>
    <values>t(UIDataPanelBase.java:400) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1669) at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307) at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96) </values>
    <values> at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:231) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157) at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:163) ... 13 more
```

Comment: Why should `Cell.getCellType` not work? For me it works. How are you using it? What error you get when you are using it?

Comment: I have updated the post with the error from error.log

Comment: Please provide stack trace as text and not as image. But as far as I could read the picture, it says there is no such method `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType()`. But that's a lie. There is that method in all `apache poi` versions. Sure you have not a mix of different `apache poi` versions in class path? This is not supported.

Comment: Your link tells "POI Version 3.14 included". So check whether you have any other `apache poi` version in class path while running. As said, this is not supported and leads to such kinds of problems.

Comment: Please show how you try calling `Cell.getCellType`. What code are you using?

Comment: @AxelRichter Yes, `getCellType()` always exists, but that does *not* always return a `CellType` enum (depending on the POI version).

Comment: @Oliver: That's true. But in `apache poi 3.14` it returns a `int` which also can be used to check the cell type against `Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING`, `Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`, ... So where is the problem?

Comment: @AxelRichter Look at the stacktrace carefully: it says the expected return type is `CellType`.

Comment: @Oliver: That's why I asked what code was used to call `Cell.getCellType`. And `CellType` does not even exists in `apache poi 3.14`. So if code using `CellType` compiles, it must be compiled against another `apache poi` version.

Comment: @AxelRichter Obviously the code was compiled with POI 4 and tries to execute with POI 3.

Comment: Apache POI is generally only backwards-compatible for a couple of releases. [POI 3.10 is over 6 years old!](http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.10-FINAL) That's a huge huge leap....

Comment: thanks for all your replies. I am using rowdata.getCell(0).getCellType()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it seem to work

```
try{
    year = (int)rowdata.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
}catch(Exception e){
    year = rowdata.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
}
```